# Cache em servidor

Tags: php, mysql, cache

Tenho um sistema que comporta mais de 2000 clientes e ele continua aumentando, e toda vez que eles fazem uma busca, ele chamam o mysql com mais de 20.000 itens (e esse numero também continua a aumentar), seria possível eu ter um cache ou fazer algo para ele não precisar buscar sempre?

Estava pensando em fazer um sistema que a palavra mais buscada cria uma arquivo no servidor com as 20,30 primeiras buscas, seria certo?

Comment: Certo e errado vai de acordo com a necessidade, tenho um server rodando redis para "segurar" consultas do banco relacional (mariadb) por X tempo. Você utiliza varnish ou algo parecido? Como que os clientes acessam esses dados do mysql, por conexão direta? Já pensou em prover uma API?

Comment: Acredito que o ideal seja cachear o resultado da consulta, o MySQL possui o `Query Cache`, mas... Isso somente irá obter o dado do cache (ao invés de "buscar denovo") se o `WHERE` for idêntico e também não possuir INSERT/UPDATE na tabela. É pouco provável que resolva, mas caso possua uma tabela que não é constantemente atualizada (isso é, existe muita leitura e baixa gravação) e não possui `WHERE` especificos (por exemplo, para cada usuário conectado no site), o `Query Cache` pode ser uma alternativa e de fácil implementação.

Comment: @rzani Não uso o varnish nem algo parecido, uso apenas o mysql e o php para back-end e respondo em json para o mobile dele.

Comment: @Inkeliz não seria viavel a o banco de dados está sempre se atualizando, ainda mais nesse começo do aplicativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cache de indexação de palavras buscadas é interessante usar Elastic Search ou Solar.

Eles permitem gerar uma indexação de chaves que funciona como cache, assim que é feito buscas em grandes quantidades de dados textuais.

Outro tipo de cache, é cache de consulta de dados.

Você identifica as querys que são realizadas com maior frequência e guarda os resultados em cache por um período. Em querys com parâmetros, você pode gerar um hash baseado nestes parâmetros e prefixar a chave do cache combinada com o hash.

Algumas ferramentas ideais para isto é o Redis, Memcached, APC, etc...